# How do I go about creating a UML diagram for large projects I didn't code?

Tags: uml, solidity, class-diagram

For a large project of mine I've been given the task to create class diagrams for existing projects similar to mine.

For example, I have to create a class diagram for [this website](https://github.com/AugurProject/augur). I wouldn't even know where to start in such a project. I'm guessing since there is no single language for such projects there isn't any handy tool that would start me off, so I presume I'll be printing off lots of code and figuring it all out in my head.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Take a lecture or two. Know what you're doing. You wouldn't trust a plumber that states he never did any plumbing (but assures he CAN do it).

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ideas which might help you:

- Extract a list of all classes from the existing code.
- For each class, find relationships to other classes (for example: class
  A uses instances of class B, class B calls certain methods from class
  C etc.).
- Find groups or clusters of classes which contribute to a
  common subtask. This can give you a rough structure of the project.
- Identify classes that deliver a major functionality for the project
  as opposed to classes which are merely helpers.
- And of course: Try to get as much information as you can from anyone familiar with the code.

In conclusion, this will typically demand a lot of familiarization with the given implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Etherscan will display a UML diagram for Solidity for contracts with verified source code using Nick Addisons sol2uml (https://github.com/naddison36/sol2uml)

For example: 
Reputation token by Augur: 
https://etherscan.io/address/0x1985365e9f78359a9B6AD760e32412f4a445E862#code
UML diagram: https://etherscan.io/viewsvg?t=1&a=0x1985365e9f78359a9B6AD760e32412f4a445E862